# When is advised PendingIntent vs. LocationListener on requestLocationUpdates?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-pendingintent

you can subscribe to requestLocationUpdates via two ways

- one by specifing a PendingIntent
- the other is by using a LocationListener

When is advised the one and when the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the component needing location updates only needs updates when the component is around -- say, an activity -- I'd use the `LocationListener` approach.

If the component needing location updates specifically will not be around -- say, an `IntentService` -- I'd use the `PendingIntent`. You can't use the `LocationListener` in this case, since there is nothing in memory to be listening for locations.