# Android Locations: PendingIntent vs. LocationListener

Tags: android, service, location, android-pendingintent, locationlistener

I am confused on when I should use a PendingIntent vs. a LocationListener for getting locations.  If I have a service that always stays alive, is it ok to use LocationListeners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the component needing location updates only needs updates when the component is around -- say, an activity -- I'd use the
>   LocationListener approach.
>
> If the component needing location updates specifically will not be
>   around -- say, an IntentService -- I'd use the PendingIntent. You
>   can't use the LocationListener in this case, since there is nothing in
>   memory to be listening for locations.

Source : [When is advised PendingIntent vs. LocationListener on requestLocationUpdates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121557/when-is-advised-pendingintent-vs-locationlistener-on-requestlocationupdates)

Comment: I saw this, I call Looper.loop() in my service so it should still be in memory. I am looking for other reasons to use one or the other.